# How to split a string which contains delimiter into multiple rows using OPENJSON function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I am trying to split the below string using OPENJSON function in SQL Server 2019:

```
DECLARE @x varchar(400)  = N'A,B,"C,1",D,'

--SELECT '["'+replace(string_escape(@x,'json'),',','","')+'"]'

SELECT 
    [Key]+1 AS Seq,
    Value 
FROM 
    OPENJSON('["' + REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(@x, 'json'), ',', '","') + '"]')
```

But the result is returned as:

[image]

I want to display it as this:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where my thinking brings me.

Note: Unexpected results of the `"'s` are NOT balanced.

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dVXOeIWi)**

```
DECLARE @x varchar(400)  = N'A,B,"C,1",D,'

Select Seq= Grp
      ,value = replace(string_agg(Value,','),'"','')
 From (
        SELECT [Key]+1 AS Seq
              ,Value 
              ,Grp = sum( case when charindex('"',Value)<=1 then 1 else 0 end ) over (order by [key]+0) 
        FROM OPENJSON('["'+replace(string_escape(@x,'json'),',','","')+'"]')
      ) A
 Group By Grp
 Order By Grp
```

**Results**

```
Seq value
1   A
2   B
3   C,1
4   D
5
```

Comment: Thanks John, yeah you are right you have seen it earlier :-). I am just trying to figure out how this OPENJSON function works so just trying out with different format of strings.

Comment: Hi John , if the string contains multiple commas within the double quotes the charindex add 0 for the middle character and the Grouping fails. For eg; DECLARE @x varchar(400)  = N'A,B,"C,1,2",D,'. The charindex of "1" becomes 0 and the SUM logic put the same Grp for 1,2" and different Grp for "C . I am trying to store the value in temp table then update the charindex of those characters(in the above eg; 1)  and then applying your logic. Is there any better way to handle this. Please let me know . Thanks

Comment: Just back in my office.  Let me take a peek.   Just may have to be a gap-and-islands approach.  Should not be an issue

Comment: @SQL006 Going to have to noodle this a bit more.  You may be better off importing CSV with quotes as the text qualifier.

Comment: Thanks  john, Yes the text qualifier is on.